# Links repeated in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

this is driving me nuts! I hope you can help me.

I'm trying to get 2 views for the same model (I need one just like in the model and the other one like another app needs it). I have created 2 serializers, 2 views and 2 urls but when I check they are repeated!

I'll try to show you the relevant part of the code:

urls.py

```
from consumptions.routers_views import MessageViewSet, MessageSapViewSet

router.register(r'messages', MessageViewSet)
router.register(r'messagesforsap', MessageSapViewSet)
```

routers_views.py

```
from .serializers import MessageSerializer, MessageSapSerializer

class MessageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = ['user','date','consumption','content','read', 'deleted']

class MessageSapViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MessageSapSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = ['user','date','consumption','content','read', 'deleted']
```

serializers.py

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    
    consumption = ConsumptionSerializer(allow_null=True)
    user = UserSerializer(allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = [
            "id",
            "user",
            "date",
            "consumption",
            "content",
            "read",
            "deleted"
        ]

class MessageSapSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    user = UserSerializer(allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = [
            "user",
            "date",
            "content",
            "read",
            "deleted"
        ]
```

My problem is that when I check the links in the main page of the api I find that links are repeated

[image]

Comment: You had called the `register(...)` method ***twice***

Comment: That just register a new URL but you can call it as many times as you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`base_name`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) (or `basename` if you use the newer DRF version) argument:

```
router.register(r'messages', MessageViewSet, base_name='messages')
router.register(r'messagesforsap', MessageSapViewSet, base_name='messagesforsap')
```

It's better in this case to explicitly set the `base_name` because your serializers share the same model and DRF might duplicate it like that trying to automatically discover the url naming pattern.